# Уточняющий оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, семантика, уточнения

> В этом лесу на соснах вы можете заметить белку или дятла

Для какой цели мог выделяться уточняющий оборот (обстоятельства места) "на соснах", если бы таковым он и задумывался?

Чем отличался бы контекст с уточняющим оборотом и без него?

Так, в справочнике Розенталя даются примеры. ***Дети расположились на поляне между кустами*** *(поляна окружена кустами, а на самой поляне их нет)*. — ***Дети расположились на поляне, между кустами*** *(кусты находятся на самой поляне)*. Можно ли в 1 пр. рассмотреть "между кустами" как определение к "на поляне"?

Comment: Здесь такого нет, лес же не на соснах.